# .nfsXXX files on visual studio code

Tags: c, linux, file, visual-studio-code, nfs

### Server:

I am currently working in a remote linux server.

### Problem:

Every time when I run my code, some .nfsXXX files spawned into my working directory.

#### My Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -lm

problem2 : problem2.o helpers.o
    $(CC) -o problem2 helpers.o problem2.o -pthread -I/path/to/header/files

.PHONY : clean

clean : 
    rm *.o $(objects) problem2
```

It shows me this when I try to **delete** those .nfs files:
[image].

[image]

The code runs perfectly fine without any error.
How to get rid of them? Why this happens?

#### My code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include "helpers.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

/**
 * @brief This function recursively traverse the source directory.
 *
 * @param dir_name : The source directory name.
*/

char **file_paths;
int file_count = 0;
int word_count = 0;

void traverseDir(char *dir_name);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int process_id; 
    file_paths = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));

    
    
    char *dir_name = argv[1];

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Main process: Please enter a source directory name.\nUsage: ./main <dir_name>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    traverseDir(dir_name);
    if (file_count == 0)
    {
        printf("Main process: No txt files found in the source directory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (file_count > 100)
    {
        printf("Main process: The number of txt files is greater than 100.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    printf("Found %d files in the source directory.\n", file_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", file_paths[i]);
    }

    int shmid;
    int f,e,m;
    
    char *shared_buffer;
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, BUFFER_SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    shared_buffer = (char *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    
    sem_t *_full_, *_empty_, *_mutex_;
    f = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    e = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), 0666 | IPC_CREAT); 
    m = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    _full_ = (sem_t *)shmat(f, 0, 0);
    _empty_ = (sem_t *)shmat(e, 0, 0);
    sem_init(_full_, 1, 0); 
    sem_init(_empty_, 1, 0); 

    int *read_file_count;
    int rKey = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    read_file_count = (int *)shmat(rKey, 0, 0);
    *read_file_count = 0;
    size_t* num_read;
    int nKey = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(size_t), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    num_read = (size_t *)shmat(nKey, 0, 0);
    *num_read = 0;
    switch (process_id = fork())
    {

    default:
                while(*read_file_count < file_count){
            FILE *fp = fopen(file_paths[*read_file_count],"r");     
            if( fp == NULL ){
                printf("Fail to open file!\n");
                exit(0);
            } else {

            }
                size_t total_read = 0;
                printf("Parent:\n");
                printf("++++++++++Reading FILE %d++++++++++\n", *read_file_count);
                while((*num_read = fread(shared_buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, fp)) > 0) {
                    
                printf("[Parent] Buffer of size %d contains: %.*s\n", 
                (int)(*num_read), (int)(*num_read), shared_buffer);
                    printf("------------------------------\n");
                    sem_post(_full_); //printf("Parent process released full.\n");
                    sem_wait(_empty_); //printf("Parent process acquired empty.\n");
                }
                fclose(fp);
                (*read_file_count)++;               
            }
        printf("Parent process: Finished.\n");
        printf("Parent process: The total number of words is %d.\n", word_count);
        break;

    case 0:
            sem_wait(_full_); printf("Child process got full+1.                 "); 
        while(*read_file_count < file_count){
        printf("Child:\n");
            printf("[Child]  Buffer of size %d contains: %.*s\n",
                (int)(*num_read), (int)(*num_read), shared_buffer);
        printf("previous word count: %d\n", word_count);
        char* my_string = (char*)malloc((*num_read + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
        memcpy(my_string, shared_buffer, *num_read); 
        my_string[*num_read] = '\0'; 
        word_count += wordCount(my_string);
        if(wordCount(my_string) != 1 && my_string[(*num_read)-1] != ' '){
            word_count--;
        }
        free(my_string);

        printf("child counted words : %d\n", word_count);
        printf("------------------------------\n");
        sem_post(_empty_); //printf("Child process released empty.\n");
        sem_wait(_full_); //printf("Child process got full. ");
        }
        printf("Child process: Finished.\n");
        exit(0);

    case -1:
    
        printf("Fork failed!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    exit(0);
}

/**
 * @brief This function recursively traverse the source directory.
 *
 * @param dir_name : The source directory name.
 */
void traverseDir(char *dir_name)
{
    
    
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir(dir_name)) != NULL)
    {
    
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
            {
                
                if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                char *new_dir_name = malloc(strlen(dir_name) + strlen(ent->d_name) + 2);
                strcpy(new_dir_name, dir_name);
                strcat(new_dir_name, "/");
                strcat(new_dir_name, ent->d_name);
                traverseDir(new_dir_name);
            }
            else
            {
                
                if (strstr(ent->d_name, ".txt") != NULL)
                {
                    char *new_file_path = malloc(strlen(dir_name) + strlen(ent->d_name) + 2);
                    strcpy(new_file_path, dir_name);
                    strcat(new_file_path, "/");
                    strcat(new_file_path, ent->d_name);
                    
                    
                    file_paths[file_count] = new_file_path;
                    file_count++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        closedir(dir);
    }
    else
    {
    
        perror("");
        return;
    }
    }
```

I actually googled but I can't find a way to remove them from the visual studio code, and most of the descriptions about the nfs is a little bit ambitious, I don't know which part of my code made this happen, as I should have correctly closed all files after they are opened.

Comment: I also know my code is very bad, if you have any idea about how to improve the code, please also lemme know <3

Comment: top search results for "`.nfs file`": https://serverfault.com/q/201294/993961, https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/What_are_nfsXXXX_files_and_how_do_I_delete_them, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System

Answer (score -1):

NFS is a system which shares file. When working properly, the .nfs files delete after being used. Sometimes when the files crash, the .nfs file stays.

Learn more here: https://www.datto.com/blog/what-is-nfs-file-share

**Answer**
To delete the files, close everything open and then type this into the terminal:

pkill -9 -u (username)

This will kill the terminal, so make sure you save everything beforehand you want. This will also affect your terminal history.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).